# ASP.NET MVC Render view in different thread

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a follow code for generating html content via `View.Render`

```
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);

using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
   controller.ViewData.Model = model;
   var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
   controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, stringWriter);
   viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
   var html = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

It's work well when I execute it in same thread that my request.
But If I wrap it into `Task.Run` I've got an error

**`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The request lifetime scope cannot be created because the HttpContext is not available.'`**

Is there way to make html generation in different thread?

Comment: Why do you want to run it on a different thread? Based on the provided code I can not spot anything which is CPU intensive that's why I don't understand why do you want to offload.